# Excel Macro - Exporting sheets as separate .CSV files

Tags: excel, vba, export-to-csv

I have a workbook with 3 sheets in them, I am using the below macro to export the sheets as .csv files. However sheet1 gets exported with the data in it and sheet2 gets exported without any data in it and is a blank file. The goal is to successfully export Sheet1 and Sheet2 as .csv files with data in them without overwriting the original workbook. Any help would be much appreciated.

```
Sub Export_Files_Click()

Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim path As String

path = ActiveWorkbook.path & "\" & Left(ActiveWorkbook.Name, InStr(ActiveWorkbook.Name, ".") - 1)
For Each ws In Worksheets
    ws.Activate
    On Error Resume Next
    ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:=path & "_" & ws.Name & ".csv", FileFormat:=xlCSV, CreateBackup:=False
Next

End Sub
```

Comment: What is the purpose of your `On Error Resume Next` ? Try removing it. It could be masking an issue. The code above works fine for me though, when used on a basic 2 sheet workbook. Also, you can replace `ws.Activate... ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs...` with `ws.SaveAs`.

Answer (score 0):

### Export Worksheets (to Separate Workbooks)

- Consider the active workbook named `Test.xlsm` containing only worksheets `Sheet1` and `Sheet2` (tab names).
- Then the following, run from this or another workbook, will save the files `Test_Sheet1.csv` (containing only the worksheet `Sheet1`) and `Test_Sheet2.csv` (containing only the worksheet `Sheet2`) to the active workbook's path (folder).

**Standard Module e.g. `Module1`**

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub ExportWorksheets()

    Dim swb As Workbook: Set swb = ActiveWorkbook
    Dim swbPathAndLeftName As String: swbPathAndLeftName _
        = swb.path & "\" & Left(swb.Name, InStrRev(swb.Name, ".") - 1) & "_"
    
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    
    Dim sws As Worksheet
    Dim dwb As Workbook
    Dim dFilePath As String
    For Each sws In swb.Worksheets
        dFilePath = swbPathAndLeftName & sws.Name & ".csv"
        sws.Copy ' copies worksheet to a new (one worksheet) workbook...
        Set dwb = ActiveWorkbook ' ... which becomes active
        Application.DisplayAlerts = False ' overwrite without confirmation
        dwb.SaveAs Filename:=dFilePath, FileFormat:=xlCSV, _
            CreateBackup:=False ', Local:=True ' if semicolon instead of comma
        Application.DisplayAlerts = True
        dwb.Close SaveChanges:=False
    Next sws

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    
    MsgBox "Worksheets exported.", vbInformation, "Export Worksheets"

End Sub
```

**The CommandButton (wherever)**

```vb
Sub Export_Files_Click()
    ExportWorksheets
End Sub
```

Comment: I tried the above code, gives me a warning saying a .tmp does not exist and then this line of code gives an error as well _sws.Copy ' copies worksheet to a new (one worksheet) workbook..._

Comment: [Here is a link](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1VjLK5ofrIY9apqGfWm5NmG5j4ulPkk7b/view?usp=sharing) to my file. Download it to your computer. In `Windows File Explorer`, create a new folder and copy the file to it. Leave the folder open so you can monitor any changes. Now open the workbook (e.g. double-click the file). On `Sheet2`, press the button `Export Files` and see in `Windows File Explorer` how the two files (`Test_Sheet1.csv` and `Test_Sheet2.csv`) were added. You could add a few more worksheets and press the button again and see the new files appearing in `Windows File Explorer`.